# Is there a way to filter VBA Userform's ListBox items by name?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, listbox, userform

I have a data-entry Userform that sends data to different databases (worksheets).

Since in the Excel file there are multiple non-database sheets, is it possible to filter out and show only the worksheets that have in the name "databases" (so I don't have to modify the code each time I add a new database).

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    For i = 0 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            Worksheets(UserForm1.ListBox1.List(i)).Activate
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hide worksheets that are not to be seen with a leading underscore. This allows me to loop all worksheets and easily hide them. You could use the same/similar approach to hide/show/activate the one sheet or sheets you want to have visible.

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
 If Not ws.Name = Me.ListBox1.Caption Then
   ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 ElseIf ws.Name = Me.ListBox1.Caption Then
   ws.Visible = xlSheetvisible
   ws.Activate
 End If
Next ws
```